# call a webservice in my struts2 application

Tags: struts2

Would anyone be able to tell me how I can call a webservice in my struts2 application..
 I Created login page in struts2 so i need to access web service to validate, if success again need to call web service to obtain data and display in jsp page of project

Comment: how will you call a web-service in normal use-case??

Comment: I am new to web service, I don't how to call, But i know to create stubs in eclipse.. After Creating Stub i not able to get which function i need to call, Because its creating large number of classes and method

Comment: what kind of services you want  to expose? i recommend to go with REST full services.Read the following for more details http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/rest-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Open your struts.xml file and specify action like :

```
<action class="CLASSNAME"
        name="ACTION_NAME" method="METHOD_NAME">
        <interceptor-ref name="authStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="json" redirect="index.jsp"></result>
    </action>
```

Use javascript / jquery post to send credential to above action. Write the action class in the same way as you write as usual in Struts